# Find Equivalence Classes and the quotient set defined by the relationship in Reals.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations, set-partition

$xTy\iff |x^{2}-2|=|y^{2}-2|$

I'd love to solve it but we don't deal in absolutes. Joke aside I have no clue where to start with this one, it has me stumped.

If I had been provided the answer to the problem I could just bump around until I got there but its not the case.

$x^{2}-y^{2}=0 \rightarrow (x+y)(x-y)=0 \rightarrow x=y \lor x=-y$

Is the only thing that I can scavenge from this, but I doubt it covers all the classes, thus I can't even begin to partition the set.

$cl(x)=\{x\in R:x,-x,x-2,2-x\}$ But I'm not sure x-2 and 2-x counts in general I think it's only valid if x=0.

Comment: Work out the cases when expressions in absolutes are positive and negative. For each, you'll get one class, $2$ in total, if I'm not mistaken. You can draw the graphs of each to get the visual representation of $x$ being related to $y$.

Comment: Bear in mind a class $[k] = \{x\in \mathbb R| xTk\} = \{x \in \mathbb R:|x^2 -2| = |k^2 - 2|\}$.  Just solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if we fix $k \in \mathbb R$ then

the equivalence class $[k]$ is by definition $\{x\in \mathbb R: |x^2 -2| = |k^2 - 2|\}$.

Now if $|x^2 - 2| = |k^2 - 2|$ then a) $x^2 -2 = k^2-2$ or b) $x^2 - 2 = -(k^2 -2) = 2-k^2$.

a) $x^2 - 2 = k^2 -2\implies x^2 = k^2 \implies x =\pm k$.

b) $x^2 - 2 = 2-k^2 \implies x^2 = 4 -k^2\implies |k| \le 2$ and $x=\pm \sqrt{4-k^2}$.

So $[k]=\{x\in \mathbb R: |x^2 -2| = |k^2 - 2|\}=$

$=\{k, -k\}$ if $|k| > 2$ and $= \{k,-k, \sqrt{4-k^2}, -\sqrt{4-k^2}\}$ if $|k| \le 2$

=====

Note:  All of this *assumes* $T$ is an equivalence relation in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't tansitivity just follows from relation $=$ being transitive ?

Comment: Oh... $|x^2 - 2|  = |y^2 - 2|$ and $|y^2-2| =|z^2 - 2|$ so ....  Um, How hard a dope slap do you think a human can apply to himself?  Well, double that and that's what i just gave to myself.

Comment: And there it is, thanks, I know where I got lost now.

Comment: Hahah +
But it's not bad to see how to do it in non-trivial way too, for sure!

Comment: Yeah, I also did it the hard way, because it looked too similar to a distance relation and those aren't always transitive thus not equivalent relations, only bothered to ask the second part of the question.